# Java .get(Calendar.YEAR) returns current year instead of self-assigned value

Tags: java

I am working on a Java project and I am puzzled by this issue which I had encountered.
I am using the GregorianCalendar in my project.

```
Member m = new OldMember(count++, "Lawrence", "98765432", new GregorianCalendar(1990,02,16));

OldMember om = (OldMember)m;
```

I have manually assigned the date of birth of this particular member above.

```
Calendar dob = om.getDob();
```

After which I retrieved the member date of birth from the class om and assigned it to a dob calender as above.

```
String DOB = dob.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + dob.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + dob.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Afterwhich, I pass the results into a String DOB which I created.

```
System.out.println("DOB: " + DOB);
```

End Result :

```
DOB: 7/1/2012 <--- Today's date instead of 16/2/1990 which I wanted.
```

Anyone mind helping me? :)

Comment: What is the `om` in your code snippet? Where does that come from?

Comment: `Calendar#get(Calendar.YEAR)` will give whatever year set in the object. You _must_ be making some error in setting. Can you show the constructor and getter code?

Comment: `new GregorianCalendar(1990,02,16)` Are you aware that you are setting it to 16 **March** (not February)? Month numbers start at 0. Also, don't prefix numbers with a 0 (as in 02), because that means the number is an octal literal.

Comment: The error must be in the OldMember class, (famous last words) it should work. 
Try: `Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(1990, 02, 16);
        System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + c.get(Calendar.YEAR));´
just to compare

Comment: This are some portions of the code found in my OldMember class
      public OldMember(int i, String n, String t, Calendar c)
      {
         super(i,n,t);
         dob = dob;
      }
   
      public Calendar getDob()
      {      
         return dob;
      }

Comment: passing calendar c to constructor,but dob = dob ? why is it there ?

Comment: Somewhere in the inheritance hierarchy for Member class you have to assign different caledar instance to the dob field

Answer (score 2):

```
public OldMember(int i, String n, String t, Calendar c) {
   super(i,n,t); 
   dob = dob;
} 

public Calendar getDob() { return dob; } ?
```

(Code from comments)

you are passing Calendar c but inside constructor there is dob = dob (assig to itself), at least you are missing this keyword

Comment: Hi there. I just look through my OldMember class and it is exactly as you mentioned.
The code worked after I changed it to

    public OldMember(int i, String n, String t, Calendar c) {
   super(i,n,t); 
   dob = c;
}

Thanks. :)

Comment: always use  this  keyword when accessing instance members this.dob = c

Comment: Never just set a dummy value for a field e.g. the Calendar, when this value is not valid.  This is more often confusing than useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you code is doing what you think it is doing.  The best way to see what it is really doing is to step through the code with a debugger.

This code behaves as expected.

```
final GregorianCalendar dob = new GregorianCalendar(1990, Calendar.MARCH, 16);
String DOB = dob.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + (dob.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + '/' + dob.get(Calendar.YEAR);
System.out.println("DOB=" + DOB);

SimpleDateFormat DDMMYYYY = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String DOB2 = DDMMYYYY.format(dob.getTime());
System.out.println("DOB2=" + DOB2);
```

prints

```
DOB=16/3/1990
DOB2=16/03/1990
```